# How to map a domain to a GCS bucket created with GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I created a GAE app to host static files, a GAE bucket is automatically created with the app, the bucket name is "myappname.appspot.com". Is it possible to map a custom domain with this bucket created with GAE app? As per Google documentation for mapping a custom domain, the bucket name should be the same as the custom domain you want to map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Your bucket name should be the same name of your custom domain.

If you don't have billing enabled, you won't be able to rename the default bucket that's created for you. So you have to start there: enable billing for your app.

After billing is enabled, you can create a new bucket and assign a new name to it. For example: cdn.example.com

Comment: Can you rename the default bucket created by GAE?

Comment: Yes, you can rename it.